# TypeScript: Imported JSON Data Type Inference Issue

Tags: json, typescript, import, casting

I am stuck on a strange behavior of TypeScript when importing a JSON data to my ReactApp.
When I have an intermediate file with the following code:
Interface.tsx

```
import { Node } from "relatives-tree/lib/types"
import data from "./data.json";
export const SOURCE = data as readonly Readonly<Node>[];
```

and then I import this code in my App it works like a charm, however, when I try to import the data directly in my App as:

```
import DataFamily from "../data.json";
//THIS WILL NOT WORK
const data: Readonly<Node[]> = DataFamily;
```

the data variable gets *error Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'readonly Readonly<{ id: string; gender: Gender; parents....*

The Node Type is defined as

```
export declare type Node = Readonly<{
    id: string;
    name: string;
    isAffected: boolean;
    gender: Gender;
    parents: readonly Relation[];
    children: readonly Relation[];
    siblings: readonly Relation[];
    spouses: readonly Relation[];
    placeholder?: boolean;
}>;
```

What am I missing in here? Also, it seems to me that using the intermediate file is a way of bypassing the type checking - in the SandBox (link bellow) I edited the data that for one member the id is a integer instead of a string and the code still works..

https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-jones-tz7mrp?file=/src/components/App/App.tsx

I tried to figure it out with ChatGPT, but he is hopeless. To me, direct import of JSON data in the App should work just as well as importing it from an intermediate file